# Stop pausing when mouse hover -Full Slider

Tags: javascript, slider

I used Full Slider (https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-full-slider) for my recent web development project. 
It is a background image slider.
Now my problem is, when the user brings his/her mouse on to the web site, slider stops at the current slide because the slider is Full Screen.
I want to stop this (this means, pausing when mouse hover). But I have no idea how to do it. Only thins I know is I have to edit one of a javascript file.
Please help me guys.

Comment: You could look for the part of the code that causes it to pause. And then share that here if you don't know what to do to it to make it not pause.

Comment: I don't know which part I have to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bootstrap.js file there's a section for the carousel

```
Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true,
    keyboard: true
  }
```

You could try removing the `pause: 'hover',` line

Edit:
In the index.html file where the carousel interval is set change it to this.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000, //changes the speed
        pause: 'none'
})
```

That worked for me.

Comment: I removed 'pause: "hover",' part.
But nothing happened.